# [Oracle], GRANT SELECT ON SYNONYM on DBLINK

Tags: oracle, dblink

I've got such case.

I've got 3 users on 2 DBs:

- A@DBDEV
- A@DBPROD
- B@DBPROD - read only user for busines user to get some data.

User A@DBPROD has SYNONYM:

```
CREATE SYNONYM S_TAB FOR TAB@DBLINK_2_DEV; --(DBLINK_2_DEV created using A@DBDEV password)
```

Now I want to:

```
GRANT SELECT ON S_TAB TO B@DBPROD;
```

but getting ORA-02021...

What is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a DB link in a `grant` statement.

```
grant select on s_tab to b;
```